# Unable to insert into my database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

It's my first time using EF and I've been banging my head with this more then I have to.

Basically, I am simply trying to add a record to the database with using a submit form in the view and a create method in the controller.

So basically, I have a very basic model and a controller with a `Create` method

Here is the code :

Model with `DbContext`:

```
using System.Data.Entity;

namespace class_project.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        public int PostId { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "no!")]
        public string Title { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "no!")]
        public string Content { get; set; }

        public Post(int PostId, string Title, string Content)
        {
            this.PostId = PostId;
            this.Title = Title;
            this.Content = Content;
        }

        public Post()
        { }

        public class PostContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Post> Posts { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
using static class_project.Models.Post;   // I AM NOT SURE ABOUT THIS PART, BUT IT WAS ABLE TO BUILD WHEN ADDED IT.

namespace class_project.Controllers
{
    public class PostsController : Controller
    {
        private PostContext db = new PostContext();

        public ActionResult Create(Post obj)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return View(obj);
            }

            db.Posts.Add(obj);

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Posts");
        }
    }
}
```

And my `View` is a standard autogenerated `Create` with two input fields (I assume that the id is generated from the db) based on the model.

```
@model class_project.Models.Post

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Post</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Comment: you are missing db.SaveChanges after the  db.Posts.Add

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to call db.SaveChanges